# Redirecting error in Python Django while using NEXT parameter

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect, http-status-code-302

website used to redirect as

```
www.example.com/login/?next=/
```

but now its redirecting as

```
www.example.com/login/?next=/login/
```

didn't make any changes in the code but now the problem has been created as throwing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, redirected too many times.
main

> urls.py

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),                 
path('login/',include(('login.urls','login'),namespace='login')),
path('', include('home.urls')),
```

> home.urls

```
url(r'^$', views.home,name='home'),
url('profile',views.profile,name="profile"),
```

> login.urls

```
path("", views.do_login),
path("logout/",LogoutView.as_view(),name="logout"),
path("password_reset/",views.CustomPasswordResetView.as_view(),name="password_reset"),
```

as I was using NEXT parameter,
in home view I tried changing to `**@login_required(/login) to @login_required**` ,
in

> login views.py

```
def do_login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'login/login.html')
    else:
        username = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        selector = request.POST['radiogroup1']
        username_exist = User.objects.filter(email=username)
```

> home views.py

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
User_Info=User_Basic_Info(request)
user_logged_in = request.user
userform = UserPostForm()
qs = request.user.notifications.unread()
print(qs)
qs.mark_all_as_read()

but changes are not reflecting, couldn't understand why, its throwing

```
"GET /login/?next=/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

have used `django.contrib.auth`

hope someone could help,
thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that it will redirect to the login, and this will again redirect to login, and again, etc.

Comment: Exactly how did yout configure the `urls.py`? and the related views.

Comment: Did you for some reason set the login required decorator on your _login view_?

Comment: Show `login.urls` and `home.urls` too. Also show your login view.